# composition of non analytic functions can be analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I was wondering if the following scenarios are possible:
1) composition of an analytic function with a non-analytic continuous function being analytic (except for trivial cases)
2) composition of two non-analytic functions being analytic.

Comment: For the second one, consider composing $\bar z$ with itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Let $U$ and $V$ be open subsets of the complex plane and let $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and $g\colon U \to V$ be *real-differentiable*. Suppose that $f\circ g$ is analytic in $U$ and that $f'(z)\ne 0$ at every point $z \in U$. **Claim**: $g$ is analytic in $U$.

*Proof*. By Cauchy-Riemann equations, for every $w\in U$ the Jacobian matrix $Df(w)$ is a scalar multiple of a rotation matrix:$$Df(w)=\alpha R_\theta.$$ The coefficient $\alpha$ does not vanish because of the assumption on $f'(z)$. Since $f\circ g$ is analytic, the same must happen for the Jacobian matrix $D(f\circ g)(z)$:
$$Df(g(z))Dg(z)=\beta R_\phi.$$
So 
$$Dg(z)=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}R_{\phi-\theta}.$$
Hence, again by Cauchy-Riemann equations, $g$ is analytic.

This does not answer your question, since you requested less regularity on $g$, but at least hints at the fact that the phenomenon is unlikely.

2) The composition of the non-analytic mapping $$z\mapsto \frac{1}{\overline{z}}$$ with itself is analytic. (This is essentially the same example as Potato.)

Comment: This is enough for my purpose. Thank you so much !

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP considers to be a "trivial case", but I can think of several examples of the composition of an analytic with a non-analytic function being analytic: (a) $\exp z$ composed with $\log z$ and (b) $z^n$ composed with $z^{1/n}$ both equal the identity function, which is trivially analytic. In both cases the function $g$ violates your assumption of real-differentiability, but I would consider them to be "non-trivial" examples that answer the OP's question.

Comment: @tparker: you are probably right. It's been 10 years since this answer (!), so I don't really remember what I was thinking back then. However, I guess I was trying to come up with some kind of general statement and that was the best I could do.